# How to set label colour in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have to three labels in my page. I need to need to give a different text colour of different label, but when I override this class it makes all label red.

```
.ui-body-c label {
    color: red !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZaqz/5/

```
<label class="labelClass" id="openSubmenu">Move to Second Page:</label>

<label class="" id=""> to  Page:</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a redLabel class

```
.redLabel {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Then apply this class to only those labels which you need to be red:

```
<label class="redLabel" id=""> to  Page:</label>
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GZaqz/6/)**